# How do I style HTML with CSS?

Tags: css, class, html, tabs

I have tried, but I can't figure out how to style these elements:

```
<div class="tabs">
<ul class="tabsNavigation">
<li><a href="#tab1">Tab1</a></li>
<li><a href="#tab2">Tab2</a></li>
<li><a href="#tab3">Tab3</a></li>
</ul>
```

How would I do that?

Comment: Can you show what you have? It's easier to change that

Comment: Can you add a little more detail as to what you are trying to achieve, what you have tried so far and what hasn’t worked for you?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you read http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just refer to

```
.tabs ul
{
}
```

or

```
.tabs ul li
{
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[Listamatic has many examples](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/listamatic/) and [a tutorial](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/listutorial/index.htm)

Answer (score 2):

Using the operator ">" (immediately after), you prevent the styles are applied to elements within the structure you are using html based. Example: If other DIVs, LIs, as these will not have changed their styles.

```
DIV.tabs {

}
DIV.tabs > .tabsNavigation {

}
DIV.tabs > .tabsNavigation > LI {

}
DIV.tabs > .tabsNavigation > LI > a {

}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to style the list itself, use:

```
ul.tabsNavigation{}
```

and if you want to style each `li`, use:

```
ul.tabsNavigation li{}
```

or the links?

```
ul.tabsNavigation a{}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.tabs>ul>li{ /* your style */ }
```

or

```
.tabsNavigation>li{ /* your style */ }
```

Remember to include your css styles.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is this:
For classes use `.className` and for id's use `#idName`

```
.className {
style: property;
}

#idName {
style: property;
}
```

Here is a JSFiddle of your example:

http://jsfiddle.net/Mutant_Tractor/aXdJ9/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can do inline styling or Use a css file to define your styles. 
for inline styling you can do the following. This will give the div tabs a red background.

```
<div class="tabs" style="background:red;">
<ul class="tabsNavigation">
<li><a href="#tab1">Tab1</a></li>
<li><a href="#tab2">Tab2</a></li>
<li><a href="#tab3">Tab3</a></li>
</ul>
```

If you want to define your style in a css file then you can reference the css file in your html file like this

```
<link href="css/yourfile.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

define the css classes in your html tags:

```
<ul class="tabsNavigation">
```

Then in your css file you would do

```
.tabsNavigation{
background:red;
border:1px solid blue;
width:400px;
height:300px;
}
```